# Tattling on fellow Mi Yodeyans

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, stackexchange, voting

We are currently in the beginning of the [2012 Mi Yodeya Moderator Election](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1).

To what extent can one avail oneself of the exception of "to'elet"="for a purpose" to the standard rules of Lashon HaRa' (slander) in discussing different candidates' qualifications for being a community moderator?

Background: the exception of To'elet is best roughly illustrated by referring to the story of Gedaliah ben Achikam. A friend of Gedaliah named Yochanon ben Kereach warned him that Yishmael ben Netanya was coming to kill him but Gedaliah refused to listen because it was Lashon HaRa' and ended up being killed ([Jeremiah 40:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1140.htm#13)-[41:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1141.htm#1)). However, Gedaliah was mistaken and should have listened to Yochanon because the Lashon HaRa' was told with a To'elet: to save Gedaliah's life.

Comment: On second thought, I dislike my way of explaining To'elet. Anyone else have an  idea? I don't want to get into too much detail in the question; let's leave that for the answers.

Comment: Or if people like it we can keep it. Whatever.

Comment: [Hirhurim](http://torahmusings.com/2012/04/lashon-ha-ra-and-political-campaigns/)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10693/loshon-hara-against-an-online-identity

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/loshon-hara-and-the-down-vote?rq=1

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31774

Comment: The question makes the assumptions that Lashon Hara applies to online identities. Since, as per [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10693/loshon-hara-against-an-online-identity), it doesn’t, should this be marked as a duplicate of the above question?

Comment: This question, which has been posted for over 10 ten years, doesn't really seem appropriate for Mi Yodeya but rather should be migrated to Meta. It is really about proper procedure for assessing potential candidates was moderators.