# Lashon hara to criticize world leaders?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking

If a Jew lives in an oppressive country and speaks negatively about that country's leader, is that considered lashon hara?

Comment: related: [Loshon hara against non-Jews?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44678/11501)