# Lashon Hara during a debate?

Tags: halacha

Many times When I debate with Christians they often deny that the Oral Law is the Law that was established all the way from Moses till now.  And that the judges had the authority to establish Torah Law.

I have cited sources from the Mishnah and Bible more then once only for them to deny them.  Is it Lashon Hara to call them liars?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44678/loshon-hara-against-non-jews

Comment: calling people liars to their face is not lashon hara, but regardless lashon hara does not apply to non-jews or to heretics (according to specific conditions, and denying Oral Law is one of them)

Comment: Thank you, I tried explaining what the Oral law was and he kept denying it