# Is it loshon hora on a director to say that a movie is bad?

Tags: loshon-hara, onaath-devarim

This question may sound strange, but I thought I read that midrabannan it is forbidden to speak loshon hora about gentiles. And I thought that maybe it would be loshon hora on a director, even if it was a gentile, to say that his movie is, for example, rated R.

Comment: I don't know of any source that it is forbidden to speak loshon hora about gentiles. Regardless, many movie directors are Jewish, so your question might apply (assuming a mumar is subject to loshon hora, which isn't simple).

Comment: May not be forbidden, but it is bad middos, isn’t it? And I thought the Torah wants us to work on our middot. So in that sense isn’t it better not to speak loshon hora about gentiles?

Comment: I don't disagree but it doesn't seem to be what the poskim say. In any event are you asking if one shouldn't say a movie is bad? Or that a movie is rated R? Those are different questions.

Comment: I realize this may just be anxiety but I am worried that I may have spoken loshon hora by saying that a movie was rated R.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44678/loshon-hara-against-non-jews

Comment: It's completely public knowledge, so why should there be a prohibition at all?

Answer (score 1):

In [Chofetz Chaim, a lesson a day](https://books.google.com/books/about/Chofetz_Chaim_a_Lesson_a_Day.html?id=SL5DQB1J6DUC) it says:

> It would seem that there is nothing derogatory about a statement of taste. To say, "I don't like dry wine," is a description of the speaker's preferences and not a critical evaluation
> of the wine. Ostensibly, then, one should be allowed to say that he
> does not like the oratory style of a given lecturer. In fact, however,
> such statements are generally prohibited, for they imply that the
> speaker lacks effectiveness.

Comment: Hey, I read that before! I read that book.