# Is it really bad to gossip about a gentile?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, lashon-hara-slander, loshon-hara

Obviously it is forbidden to speak Loshon Hora about a Jew unless it is L'Toeles or perhaps about an apikores. But is there anything bad about gossiping about a gentile?

Comment: What’s l’toeles?

Comment: @Curious Yid, speaking Loshon Hora but for a constructive purpose. (Hence it's technically not Loshon Hora)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44678/loshon-hara-against-non-jews

Comment: Well of course because you only have one set of *middos*.

Comment: If it's really a toeles. It's still entirely possible to speak lashon hara about an apikores. Just bc someone might have such a status does not mean we should have satisfaction from speaking negatively about him

Answer (score 3):

If I met anyone who thought it was okay to:

1. Gossip about non Jews
2. Sleep with the partners of non Jews
3. Imply it's okay to steal from or give less advantageous terms to non Jews.

I would consider that person a terrible sinner. I would protest such a person marrying my Jewish children.

You can tell a lot about a person based on how they treat the "outside groups" or anyone or anything they believe is beneath them. Eliezer knew Rebecca would be an excellent wife for Isaac because of how she treated animals. If Eliezer were to witness her hurting animals for no reason, gossiping or being unethical to the people around her, even if it was technically legal according to halakha, he would NOT have brought her to Isaac for marriage. There's no halakha that says a person needs to water someone else's animals who are thirsty, but when Eliezer saw her water his camels he knew that said more about her goodness as a person than how much halakha she followed.

Comment: Many people think that something that is not prohibited is necessarily an invitation to do so. Question might be the obvious one, if it's bad for members of your community why would it be uplifting for outside members? There is no mention of not having a father-daughter relationship, will they relate because of this absence?

Comment: The Torah does not literally prohibit sexual intercourse between father and daughter as in Leviticus 18, nor is it permissible, rabbis over time argue that the prohibition is obvious based on the prohibition of intercourse between grandfather and granddaughter

Comment: the torah does literally prohibit it even if not explicitly