# Lashon Hara about someone you do not know?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, bein-adam-lachavero

Is it considered Lashon Hara if a person speaks badly about a person he does not actually know? And, what about if nobody really knows him?

For example, would saying something bad about another user in a forum such as Mi Yodeya constitute LH? Since (for arguments sake) nobody knows the true identity of userXYZ, would it be considered a transgression?

Note- I am not referring to it being bad for one's own middot to speak badly about others (even those he doesn't know), but rather specifically referring to the issur of Lashon Hara in this case.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10693/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17617/759