# Rechilus and Close Votes

Tags: lashon-hara-slander, stackexchange

Say that someone (Reuven) posts something on here. A person (Shimon) votes to close it.

Now, someone else (Levi) comes along, sees this close vote, and disagrees with it. So he might comment on the post and ping Shimon why he thinks the post shouldn't be closed.

Is there an issue of Rechilus, saying something that makes one person upset at another (see Chafetz Chaim, Rechilus 1:2)?

Comment: Why is it embarrassing to Shimon that someone disagrees with him? Also, if someone doesn't want others  discussing their actions, they shouldn't be participating on this site.

Comment: @DoubleAA By the same token, if someone doesn't want their actions being discussed they should lock themselves up in their house for their entire life. Fair enough about embarrassment, but it still might make Reuven upset that Shimon voted to close his post.

Comment: that's not the same token. expressing an opinion in public and acting on it in a way that affects others is not the opposite of locking yourself in your house.

Comment: You can see who votes to close something (before it is closed)? On a duplicate, you see the first close voter, yes. Otherwise? (cc @DoubleAA because you are here and likely to know).

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/loshon-hara-and-the-down-vote?rq=1

Comment: @Yishai Mods can see close voter's identities before it's closed, but other's can't. AFAIK. Even mods can't see delete vote's ids. I don't remember about reopen votes.

Comment: [As long as there is a specific purpose to it, it should be fine](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76871/8775). If you are interested, I will expand this into an answer. If not, consider clarifying in your question why you are not interested.